# How to create a link to another page AND specify another URL for an iframe on that page?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page called *dash.php* and in it is an *iframe (id="iframe")*. 
On a third page I have links:

```
<a href="dash.php">Add</a>
<a href="dash.php">Edit</a>
```

- When the Add link is clicked, I want to switch to the dash.php page
  AND have it load a **specific** page in the iframe.
- When the Edit link is clicked, I want to switch to the dash.php page
  AND have it load a **different** specific page in the iframe.

I am drawing a blank on how to do this, I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra parameter in your URL should fix it:

**1. Main page index.php**

Add -> `href="dash.php?content=add"`

Edit -> `href="dash.php?content=edit"`

**2. dash.php**

***2.1.*** Grab content value:

```
$content = $_GET['content'];
```

***2.2.*** Test it:

```
if($content =='add')
    $myIFrame = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
else
    $myIFrame = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
```

***2.3.*** Display your iframe by setting its source:

```
src="<?= $myIFrame ?>"
```

As you can see, no need of Javascript here.

**

### EDIT:

**

However, if you need a working JS, here it is, using the same *main.php* file:

```
var iframe;
iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

function $_GET(param) {
    var vars = {};
        window.location.href.replace( 
            /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
            function( m, key, value ) { // callback
                vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
            }
        );

    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}

    if($_GET('content') == 'add')
        iframe.src="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    else
        iframe.src="http://www.w3schools.com";
```

Comment: I thought there might be some special way by adding an attribute to the <a> tag or something that I didn't know about. Thank you.